# Some terminologies in Wirth's book and the satisfying of deterministic algorithm

Tags: finite-automata, compilers

I am going through Wirth's Textbook on Compiler design . After proceeding though 
some pages ,  I realized I have taken for granted my understanding of some
of the terminologies that have been used . For example ,the following terms :

[image]

the examples mentioned in the lines in the screenshot refer to the following set of equations :

[image]

Later on while describing the possibility of the conditions of deterministic algorithms being 
satisfied it says for an expresion of the following form :

"term_0 | term_1"

the terms must not feature any common starting symbols .And then it says this results in the exclusion of 
left recusrsion . If we consider the left recursive production :

A = A "a" | "b"

then the requirement is violated "b" is also a start symbol of "A" .

How is "b" a start symbol of "A" ? Basically from the definitions given I understood start symbol means
the symbol for which an equation is deifined first ?

Why does common start symbol disturb the conditions of deterministic algorithm ?

Comment: Please replace the image with text, to make the text searchable.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Answer (score 3):

The definition of *start symbol* that you quote has nothing to do with the definition of *start symbol* in the context of deterministic grammars. Here is a correct definition:

> A terminal $a$ is a *start symbol* of a sequential form $\alpha$ if $\alpha \Rightarrow^* aw$ for some $w \in \Sigma^*$.

In words, $a$ is a start symbol of $\alpha$ if $\alpha$ generates some word starting in $a$.

In your example, $Aa$ generates the word $ba$, and so it shares a start symbol with $b$.

Why is sharing a start symbol bad? Suppose you are trying to parse $A$, and are encountering $b$. Which production do you choose? $Aa$ or $b$? It is impossible to tell without looking ahead. The deterministic algorithm considered by Wirth has no lookahead, and so this situation is problematic for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply . Any material that you can suggest for learning about this topic ?

Comment: Wirth's book is really old fashioned. Pick up a more recent one.

Comment: Would I be right if i say that the pre-requisites haven't been  arranged in a proper sequence , like , it comes up with few things which requires prior explanation which are missing ? Any suggestions for other books ? A one that is legally available for free in pdf format will be nice .

Comment: Where can I find the definition of start symbok that you have quoted in your anser ?

Comment: The definition is pretty standard. I bet you can find it in the "dragon" book. Unfortunately textbooks tend not to be freely available, but you can find them on libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot .what about kastens ?

Comment: Never heard of it. I'm not an expert on textbooks.

Comment: By definition parsing is about verifying the conformity to established rules of syntax right ? So if we encounter "b" as the first symbol ,irrespective of whether the next symbol is going to be a blank string or "a" , we will be still knowing that the statement (or expression or line of code ) has a valid syntax ,so why to be bothered about which prod to choose . Isn't it so ?

Comment: Parsing is about understanding the structure of a text according to the rules of syntax. When you parse a C program, you don't just check that it conforms to the syntax – you construct a parse tree.

Comment: When you say "lookahead" ..does it mean taking a decision based on the next symbol (or next few symbols ) ?

Comment: @EddieDorphy Yes, that's the meaning of lookahead.